# Remove [css-expressions] as synonym of [css]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[css-expressions](/questions/tagged/css-expressions) shouldn't be a synonym of [css](/questions/tagged/css).
Dynamic properties (CSS expressions) have more to do with JavaScript than CSS.

By the way how do you vote the reversal? Is it only available to moderators?

Comment: I never really understood why that one was synonymized...

Comment: Probably because people don't understand the difference between the two.  "Expressions" is a very generic term.

Comment: @charles I guess the voting threshold (5+) is sometimes too low for popular tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I removed the synonym.  Unfortunately the two tags had been merged at some point, and there's no way to reverse that.  The [css-expressions](/questions/tagged/css-expressions) tag will have to be added manually to any question where it applies.

Comment: I tried to re-tag a question and it didn't work. And the tag still redirects to [tag:css].

Comment: @Knu That's weird, you have plenty of reputation to create a new tag.  Which question?  Also, `css-expressions` is not redirecting for me.

Comment: I will use "css-expression" instead and then add the plural as a synonym.

Comment: @Knu I just created `css-expressions`.  See if you can use it now.

Comment: @Knu Can you see that the tag was created now, and that it no longer maps to `css`?  Unfortunately I don't know much about how tag synonyms are implemented, so I don't know if this is a caching issue or what.  Have you tried restarting your browser, or switching to FF?

Comment: You should try yourself: try to tag [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1547965/248058). edit: OK I have no idea how you did that: it's not working here.

Comment: @Knu It seems to be working for me.

Comment: @Knu When I click on the `css-expressions` tag it doesn't go to the `css` page anymore, it goes to the page listing the two questions I retagged.  Mod rights don't override synonym mappings.  If I try to use a synonymized tag, it gets replaced.

Comment: It must be caching then. `[css-expressions]` still redirects me to `[css]`.

Comment: @dennis you mean I am on a different server than Bill?

Comment: @Knu: As far as my limited knowledge about these things goes, just a different CDN endpoint. If this is a caching issue, it should correct itself soonish.

Comment: I just checked, and we now have both [css-expressions] and [css-expression]. Two distinct tags, neither synonyms of one another nor of [css]. Personally I'd go with [css-expressions] as Microsoft informally calls them (formally [dynamic-properties]), rather than the function name `expression()` itself...

Comment: (Also makes it consistent with the other [css-*] tags even though this one's non-standard, just because...)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Confirmed. It's effectively desynonymized.

Comment: @Dennis: ... and I've gone ahead and synonymized them. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-expressions/synonyms

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn could you add "dynamic properties" as a synonym?